# make netbeans debugger run from new dist files

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been trying to make a code change stick, I've searched high and low to find a solution aside from "re-install netbeans" because I've done that while removing all cached data from my roaming profile on windows.

steps I've taken;

Apply Code Changes
Terminated my server and reloaded
Cleaned and built it x 2000
Removed the cache and tried again
Tried a different version of netbeans
Replaced the local server
Re-installed without computer restart
Re-installed with computer restart
Re-installed with computer restart and removing all trace that I can find of netbeans
Sworn vengance for the lost brain cells and time, for my children's children

Cried

After my third re-install, the change I've made to a java file is still not being respected. Does anyone know, in version 11.1, whether I can force the debugger to always load from the newly created dist files?

Also, in the '''build''' directory, can I just delete the class files as a solution? I haven't dared yet just in case.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Or if that is not practical, can you [edit] your question to show us what type of project this is (ant-based, maven-based, POJO, web app, etc)? And what is the code change that is not taking effect? Are you able to at least create a simple "hello world" program that prints to the console - and then change that successfully?

Comment: Also, can you clarify the steps in your question? For example, _removed the cache_ - which cache are you referring to, and how did you remove it? _terminated my server_ - what server are you referring to, and what does "terminate" mean here? And so on... These details may make it much easier to provide help.

Comment: it just started working, there is no answer, but I'll do this next time thanks andrewjames.

Comment: OK - thank you for the update. Glad it's now working! If this question cannot be answered, it should probably be closed.

Comment: thanks haha! I think it's just too much for the IDE to cope with, having multiple massive projects running at the same time, sometimes I think it just gets stuck in some weird cached state. I've voted to close

Comment: OK, understood. One last thing that may be worth checking: Open NetBeans and go to Help > About. Make a note of the location of the "User Directory". Open that directory in a file browser, and go to the var/log sub-directory. Inspect the `messages.log` file for any errors which seem to happen at the time you were having problems.